# Riemann functions on [a,b] are closed under uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

So if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ and each $f_n$ is Riemann integrable (on [a,b]), then would f also be Riemann integrable (on [a,b])?

If so, then could we go on to say that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b f_n(x) dx$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both statements are true, and follow from uniform convergence thusly: given $\epsilon>0$, choose $N$ such that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then for $n\le N$,
$$
\bigg| \sum_{j=1}^n f(x_j^*)(x_j-x_{j-1}) - \sum_{j=1}^n f_n(x_j^*)(x_j-x_{j-1}) \bigg| \le \sum_{j=1}^n \epsilon (x_j-x_{j-1}) = \epsilon(b-a).
$$